# Can having multiple personalities help productivity and decision making under pressure?

Tags: personality, decision-making

I understand having Dissociative Identity Disorder (DID) is not good thing but what about a mild dosage of DID under control, can it help? I am not referring to different roles that *same* person can play, am talking about different personalities with different emotional temperaments in same person.

Some examples:

Developing boss and worker personalities within a person, can it help overcoming chronic procrastination ?

Having a written contract with one self as if the person is two different person help recovering alcoholics?

There are lots of well known cognitive biases in decision making such as loss avoidance, endowment effect etc., greed & fear interfering with objective decision making. Instead of training hard to discipline oneself to think objectively can we simply pretend we are detached third party and make those emotionally demanding decisions objectively?

Imagine a fearful situation, instead of trying to solve the phobia how about just inventing a macho personality and switching to it !? Is the solution lot simpler and require less emotional effort when dealing with phobia?
How about solving the fear of public speaking by switching to Mr. Friendly and cool.. will these kind of inner segregation work?

One more example from poker, when the situation becomes emotionally demanding, is it possible to simply switch to third person whose monthly rent money is not at risk and escape all those sweating and heart pounding and make objective decisions!?

Sure all the problems I mentioned procrastination, phobias, addiction, blinding emotions, fear of public speaking all are complex issues requiring more work but I wanted to know how much 'creating and personality switching' can help!

Comment: There is much debate as to whether this disorder actually exists, but assuming it does, it's not really anything mild or controllable.

Comment: Transpersonal psychology includes the idea of "dialoging" with parts of the personality. You could look for info on that. I know what you are talking about, but it makes most people very uneasy if you describe it.